# Why do I get an Segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code works fine on codeblocks compiler on my computer but when I upload it to an online editor I get an Segmentation fault error and I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ifstream stream(argv[1]);
    char line[1000];
    int x,last=-1;
    while (stream>>line)
    {
        x = atoi(strtok(line,","));
        cout<<x;
        last=x;
        while(x=atoi(strtok(NULL,",")))
        {
            if(x!=last)
            {
                cout<<","<<x;
                last=x;
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> You are given a sorted list of numbers with duplicates. Print out the sorted list with duplicates removed.

And this is the input

```
6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
2,2,2,2,2
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,16,17
13,14,14,15,16,17,17,17,18
15,16,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,20
2,3,4,5,5
13,14,15,16,17
10,11,12,13,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16
12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18
5,6,7,8,9,10,11
14,14,14,15,15,16,17,17,18,19,19,20,21,22
13,14,15,16,16,17,17,18
15,16,17,18,19,20,21,21,21,21,22,22
6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,12,12,13
12,12,13,14,15,15,16,17,17,18,19,19,20,21
8,9,9,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14,15
12,13,14,15,16,17,18
1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: What "online editor"? You have left us with nothing but guesswork.

Comment: BTW if that code is supposed to read a line at a time, you've done it wrong. And I have no idea why you're using C-arrays for string storage. Or C functions for string manipulation. You're not doing `strtok` properly either (where is your check for the final token???). In fact, the more I look at this, the more wrong it gets.

Comment: I can't figure out what this line is trying to do: `while(x=atoi(strtok(NULL,",")))`.  Why are you calling `strtok` on `NULL`?  Also, is the assignment operator maybe supposed to be `==` instead?

Comment: @Carlton NULL to `strtok` is fine. NULL to `atoi` is suspect.

Comment: I read the lines from files that way because of the way the input file is formatted and I used strtok to separate the numbers from char arrays.
The

Comment: @ams, I get an exception (read access violation) when calling `strtok(NULL, ",")` with MSVC2013.

Comment: @Carlton, Yeah, it's not OK on the _first_ invocation, but the OP didn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `atoi` with the result of `strtok`. 
If `strtok` doesn't find anything it returns a null pointer.
This is the case at the end of the line.

So you are passing a null pointer to `atoi` which then leads to a crash.

Using your example this should work:
    #define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    ifstream stream(argv[1]);
    char line[1000];
    char* ln;
    char* num;
    int x;
    int last;

    while (stream >> line)
    {
        ln = line;
        last = -1;
        while (num = strtok(ln, ","))
        {
            x = atoi(num);
            if (x != last)
            {
                if(last != -1) cout << "," << x;
                else cout << x;
                last = x;
            }
            ln = NULL;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Another solution with checking for valid paramters and w/o `strtok` and `atoi`:

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <file>";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream stream(argv[1]);
    if (!stream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file \"" << argv[1] << "\"";
        return 2;
    }

    char line[1000];
    while (stream >> line)
    {
        int last = -1;
        int x = 0;
        for (char* pos = line; pos < line + strlen(line); pos++)
        {
            if (*pos >= '0' && *pos <= '9')
            {
                x = (x * 10) + (*pos - '0');
            }
            else
            {
                if (last != x)
                {
                    if (last != -1) {
                        cout << ',';
                    }
                    cout << x;
                    last = x;
                }
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in codeblock atoi on NULL returned the 0 value so I didn't know that will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking us to guess, let's start at the top ....

The code doesn't check that `argv[1]` is valid. If not, then you just dereferenced a null-pointer, and that caused your segmentation fault.

Does your "online editor" pass parameters? I suggest checking `argc > 1`.

---

Next, your code looks like it will pass a null pointer to `atoi` at the end of every line. That's another segmentation fault.

Comment: A quick test with VS2012 and a valid input file crashes on `atoi`.